# Javascript ternary operator chaining error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this if else expression filtering elements inside `dogs[] courses[] departments[]` the first snippet definitely works the way I want but my problem is its not reusable and the way is es5-ish.

**1st snippet**

```
    if (item == 'dogs') {
      item = 'dogs';
      return this[`${item}`].filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item));
    } else if (item == 'courses') {
      item = 'courses';
      return this[`${item}`].filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item));
    } else if (item == 'departments') {
      item = 'departments';
      this.dept = this.deptControl.value;
      return this[`${item}`].filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item.name));
    }
```

In this snippet I tried my best to shorten the es5-ish code but the `deptartments[]` does not work, the way I want

**2nd snippet**

```
    item =
      item == 'dogs' ? 'dogs'
        : item == 'courses' ? 'courses'
        : item == 'departments' ? 'departments' : '';

    return this[`${item}`].filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item == 'departments' ? item.name : item));
```

and the `department[]` in this snippet is likewise doesn't work the way I want

**3rd snippet**

```
    item =
     item == 'dogs' ? 'dogs'
        : item == 'courses' ? 'courses'
        : item == 'departments' ? 'departments' : '';

    // let patch = item == 'departments' ? item.name : item;
    let patch = item == 'departments' ? item['name'] : item;

    return this[`${item}`].filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(patch));
```

Please help me how to fix my issue in the `departments[]` block, using ternary operator, not the old style if..else

Comment: Parethesis won't bite.

Comment: Or just `item = item || ""`

Comment: You only set `this.dept` in the first block.

Comment: @adeneo where should i put the `item = item || ""` ?

Comment: You'd just replace the entire ternary with it? The second ternary, and the entire filter function, makes no sense. If `item` is a string, then get `item.name`, and you're filtering just one item ?

Comment: There is no relation between `if-else`/`?:` and ES5/ES6. The major problem with your code is the missing `else` branch. Please note that the conditional op enforces `else`, which avoids this kind of logical errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a different variable name in the filter, like `x`:

```
return {dogs:1,courses:1,departments:1}[item] ? this[item].filter(x => 
        new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item == 'departments' ? x.name : x))
    : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you're setting a value if it's department, I think perhaps a `switch` statement would be good here. How about something like this?

```
const testItem = (items, data) => {
  return items.filter(item => new RegExp(`^${data}`, 'gi').test(item))
}

switch (item) {
  case 'dogs':
  case 'courses':
    return testItem(this[item], data)
  case 'departments':
    this.dept = this.deptControl.value
    return testItem(this[item], data)
}
```

This is my suggestion for the following reasons:

- Write code for humans, not computers. The more readable and maintainable solution is the better one.
- **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself - try to put common operations into smaller functions (this is not only more maintainable, but the interpreter can make better optimisations)

Notice how the `testItem` function is reused, and the same instruction is executed when `item` is dogs or courses. Furthermore, although this sample doesn't have any equality operators, you should use `===` instead of `==` in Javascript :) (I know, it's confusing...)